# How can I resolve this error when calling v-for?

Tags: npm

basically my error is that when I run npm run build on the project it points out that it can't find my manuals list

**npm error:
npm run build

> vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build
> src/views/ManuaisView.vue:11:80 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'manuais'.
> 11  **

Found 1 error.

Code:

```
       <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-4">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 px-4" v-for="(manual, idx) in manuais" :key="manual.key">
              <div class="h-full p-8 text-center hover:bg-white rounded-md hover:shadow-xl transition duration-200">
                <div class="inline-flex h-16 w-16 mb-6 mx-auto items-center justify-center text-white bg-vermelho rounded-lg">
                  <i class="far fa-file-pdf fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl leading-tight font-bold">{{manual.nome}}</h3>
                <p>{{manual.descritivo}}</p>
                <p>{{manual.link}}</p>
                
              </div>
            </div>
       
         
        
        
     
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>


</template>


<script lang="ts">
import { meudb } from '../db';

var post:any = [];
var items: any;
const postRef = meudb.ref('********').once('value', (snapshot) => {
  const documents = snapshot.val();
  snapshot.forEach(d => {
    post.push({nome:d.val().nome, descritivo:d.val().descritivo, link:d.val().nivel})
  });
  items = documents
  console.log(post);
  // do something with documents
});


console.log(postRef);
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      manuais: post,
     // manuais: [],
    }
  },
  firebase: {
      manuais: {
        source: meudb.ref('********'),
         asObject: true
      }

  
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `manuais` value you should set it to an empty array in its definition (in the `data`) and update its value in the `mounted` lifecycle ([check documentation here](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted)

Example :

```js
export default {

    data: () => {
        return {
            manuais: [],
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        var post: any = [];
        var items: any;
        const postRef = meudb.ref('********').once('value', (snapshot) => {
            const documents = snapshot.val();
            snapshot.forEach(d => {
                post.push({
                    nome: d.val().nome,
                    descritivo: d.val().descritivo,
                    link: d.val().nivel
                })
            });
            items = documents
            // do something with documents
        });
        this.manuais = post; // <-- here updating the value

    }
}
```

---

### Working snippet

Here is a little snippet for you to better undestand how works v for.

In your case, if you apply this logic, your code might work

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    manuais: []
  }),

  mounted() {
    // get data from dataBase here
    this.manuais = [{
      name: 'foo'
    }, {
      name: 'bar'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="manual in manuals">{{ manual.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There was an error in the manual variable:Property 'manuais' does not exist on type '{ data(): { manuais: never[]; }; mounted(): void; }'

Comment: So what I want is to read manuals that have values ​​that I get from the database, but the error it's giving is when I run "npm run build" it says that it can't find "manuals" inside v-for

Comment: I've updated my answer. I would recommand changing your logic as what I did and check if it works better ;)